# Rails: Connect 2 models with 1 form using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Been experimenting a lot with Rails lately and I'm currently working on a project. What I wish to accomplish is to have one login form for 2 set of tables, in the same db.

One called user and the other called member. I'm on the path of making it so that if you register your email with one of them, you can't register with the other. To avoid that duplication bug if you sign up for both. However what I can't seem to figure out is how to create a form_for that checks if the login data is present in either user or member, then log them in respectively.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Not sure how to tweak this bugger.

Comment: Just want to get some clarification. Is it that you want one person to either register as a `user` _or_ as a `member`, but not both? Or is it that you want it so that one person can register as a `user` _and_ as a `member`, but you just don't want to store their email in the database twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite Devise controllers and write your own custom create function to determine which model to call to save. You can follow the documentation here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Another way I can propose is that you simply use devise controllers and only change the view. Since the forms are the same, you extract your form into a partial and then overwrite devise view files to use your partial. You can follow the documentation here to overwrite devise views: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Since your user and member are quite similar, you may want to consider subclassing your member from user (or the other way) so that the validation for email is in user and member will also gain that validation. User and member can share the same table.

For your login form, you can use the same form but you need to direct it to your own custom controller which will then checks the 2 models and then return the result. Follow the steps in overwriting devise controllers as above.